# Database of wheelchair-accessible places

Tags: data-request, medical, transportation

I want to know whether a place is wheelchair-accessible or not.

Data for the whole world would be best, but data for specific countries/cities is OK too.

Data must be reusable in Wikivoyage, which is [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licensed.

Answer (score 6):

NPR has been developing [a crowdsourced database of accessible playgrounds](http://www.playgroundsforeveryone.com/) in the US. The data is downloadable as CSV or JSON. The license for the data isn't clearly stated, but the language suggests that they want it to be freely used.

Answer (score 3):

There is [WheelMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Wheelmap), a map based on OpenStreetMap which highlights wheelchair-accessibility tags. There is also supposedly [Rollstuhlkarte](http://www.rollstuhlkarte.ch/#) but it doesn't seem to be actually showing any wheelchair symbols.

In Australia, we're working on wheelchair accessibility data standards for buildings in [OpenCouncilData.org](http://opencouncildata.org), but there's [not much published data](http://data.gov.au/dataset?q=wheelchair&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc) of this type yet.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but: You might want to consider using [accessibility.cloud](https://www.accessibility.cloud). It provides a standardized way to access place accessibility data over multiple datasets, including the data from wheelmap.org, and others.

Comment: looks like its still in beta only....know when it comes out?

Comment: What is the license of the data? For instance, can I use this API to build a list of accessible bakeries and embed this list in my $1 proprietary app?

Comment: Could you please clarify the status of the project: Is it usable in production already? Is the API considered rather stable? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the data for production apps, just sign up and get your account approved to see the available sources. Many data sources are CC or ODbL licensed, for proprietary licenses you can request access. For higher request volumes or faster responses it's of a good idea to put a cache in front of it, or simply write an email to get data in another format. The JSON API is not going to change in the near future, but attribute names are going to change slightly (not significantly for most apps though). I'm one of the developers, we're open for suggestions :)